# ffmpeg closes with "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted" in android

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running FFmpeg in my app and specifically in "Android 11" I am getting this error from several users

I have researched a lot but no solution found.

I thought there is something wrong with the codec parameter that is being passed since it is saying  "incorrect codec parameters" but most of the parameters looks good.

also verified if all the required file permission are granted and those are good too

now I m unable to find the problem,

please help, thanks

```
Command:
/data/app/~~hyrHVcslcfdQcguX0rauRA==/<AppPackage>-QbDCul7FXU4tVniSDeP1Sg==/lib/arm64/libffmpeg.so -i /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20220414-WA0010.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -map 0:V -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -c:s mov_text -segment_time 26 -g 26 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*26) -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment -preset ultrafast /storage/emulated/0/Movies/splitVideoFolder/split_video%03d.mp4

Error:
ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
  configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/Tanner/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/local/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android21-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/Tanner/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-shared --disable-ffplay --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --enable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
  libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20220414-WA0010.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
  Duration: 00:01:30.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 671 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 576x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 539 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0xb400007727c64800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xb400007727c64800] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xb400007727c64800] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0xb400007727c64800] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=26 keyint_min=2 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[segment @ 0xb400007727c28800] Opening '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/splitVideoFolder/split_video000.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 0xb400007727c28800] Failed to open segment '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/splitVideoFolder/split_video000.mp4'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
[aac @ 0xb400007727c65700] Qavg: 18220.703
[aac @ 0xb400007727c65700] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Writing to `/storage/emulated/0` and sub-folders is prohibited for regular apps since Android 11 (except for the app-private sub-folder `Android/data/<packagename>`. There are dozen of similar questions on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: But we can write to movies folder for videos and normally I am not getting (Operation permitted) error every time. If this happen because of Directory then there should be message permission denied rather than operation permitted.